# Jquery change value on input

Tags: jquery

Hi have an hidden input into an display:none div . I need to chenge the value of my input hidden but i can't..
I try this:

```
<div style='display:none'>
   <input id='hidden_input' name='xxx' type='hidden' value='' />
</div>

$("#hidden_input").val('test');
```

Hey help??

Comment: This should work. What happens or doesn't happen? When are you calling the script?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/FXbD6/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you included the jQuery library in your page, and put that line changing the value in the correct place?

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="location/of/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#hidden_input").val('test');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

see this, could help you http://jsfiddle.net/g2fsQ/

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote should work.
You also may have forgotten this bit of code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```