# Is it possible to change the string value in a radio button with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="EmbedSizeID" value="ASP.NET"> ASP.NET
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="EmbedSizeID" value="JSP/JAVA"> JSP/JAVA
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="EmbedSizeID" value="NODE.JS"> NODE.JS
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="EmbedSizeID" value="PHP"> PHP
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="EmbedSizeID" value="PYTHON"> PYTHON
</form>
```

On each of the radios, if you see the text strings "ASP.NET, JSP/JAVA", etc., I was wondering if it is possible to change/replace those strings with the `.attr()` function? Or if there is another way? I'm trying to recycle the same radios so I don't have to duplicate so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery change value on input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041294/jquery-change-value-on-input)

Comment: Yes. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Use the `.val()` function to change the `value` attribute.

Comment: yes , i tried using .attr() but that wasn't a good method @j08691

Comment: Would those functions beginning with dots, `.attr()` and `.val()`, more properly be called *methods*? Not familiar with the language but they look like methods to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the text in a span so you can refer to it with a selector.

Then you can do:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $(":radio[name=EmbedSizeID][value='ASP.NET']").next("span").text("New text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="EmbedSizeID" value="ASP.NET"><span> ASP.NET</span>
<br>
<button id="button">Change radio</button>
```

Comment: I think you need to put quotes around the value attribute due to the period. Didn't work for me as-is when I tested it.

Comment: I didn't think period had any special meaning in attribute selectors, but I've fixed it.

Comment: The alternative is double escaping it like `[value=ASP\\.NET]`.

Comment: I suspect it's probably searching for the `.` first as a class prefix, rather than first parsing the square brackets as attribute selectors. The selector parser in jQuery is somewhat ad hoc.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry if I wasn't clear enough on my question , I was referring to the texts outside of the input functions.

Comment: I tried adding your code into a  jquery function so that when you click a hyperlink or an anchor , it will change the string, but its not working correctly . @Barmar

Comment: I had `ASP.net` instead of `ASP.NET` in my code. I've fixed it, and the demo above works.

Comment: Oh I see, that was why it didn't work. Alright sweet, thanks for the help!